# How to display a custom Outlook Window?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'm developing a C# program where you enter an Outlook category name and it opens an Outlook window, which shows all the mails received with that category tag.

*For example:*
The user enters the Category-Tag "Work" and it launches Outlook and shows all the mails he received and tagged with the Category "Work".

I was able to open the "Send Email" window, but that was not my intention:D

The code:

```
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook._NameSpace clientNameSpace = (Outlook._NameSpace)outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        Outlook.PostItem postitem = (Outlook.PostItem) outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olPostItem);
        postitem.Display(true);
```

Comment: Do you want to launch Outlook application?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to be more specific in what you need, and also to post whatever attempt you have for what you are trying to achieve. Right now the question is kind of unclear. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sham exactly, and if outlook is already launched, it should open a new window

Comment: @Mete Use `System.Diagnostic.Process` class to open `Outlook.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "Send Email" you mean opening a draft message that you can send? You need MailItem object, not PostItem:

```
    Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook._NameSpace clientNameSpace = (Outlook._NameSpace)outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

    Outlook.MailItem mailitem = (Outlook.MailItemItem) outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mailitem.Subject = "My test message";
    mailitem.Display(true);
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. The Thing is: I dont want to send a Email with this programm, i just want to view the already received Mails. So for example: I enter the category "Work" and I get all the Mails i received and tagged with "Work".

Comment: Then you shouldn't be calling Aplication.CreateItem. If you know the folder where the mesdsages reside, open that folder (Namespace.GetDefaultFolder, NAmespace.Folders collection, etc.) and then search using Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, i was able to open the outlook inbox!      (with: var b = clientNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox); b.Display();)      Now i just need to figure out, how to filter the inbox with the entered category tag

Comment: Why do you display the Inbox? What you need is Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict (where Items comes from the MAPIFolder.Items property).

Comment: I could just open Outlook myself and choose to filter the inbox with a category, but i want to skip these parts, so that for example: i only enter "finance" and it automatically displays all the mails i received and tagged with this category

Answer (score 0):

You can create different types of items in Outlook using the CreateItem method.
The type of project you create depends on the parameters of CreateItem.

For item type, please see the following link:：[OlItemType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olitemtype?view=outlook-pia)

Comment: Why do i need to create a item, if i just want to look at aleady existing Mail items?

Comment: Hi Mete, If you want to find a specific email, you can check out this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-within-a-specific-folder?view=vs-2017